# Navigating in angular 2 webapp with authentication system

Tags: angular, local-storage, auth0

I'm creating an angular2 webapp with an authenticated system based on Auth0.
I'm also using Auth Guard which check on secured pages if token is still valid.

But now I would like to deal with localStorage.

As many webapp, when the user closes the browser, I would like the user to be disconnected. So I found the solution : clearing the `localStorage` with `onbeforeunload`. But this method also delete data when refreshing or closing the tab. 
And if I use `sessionStorage`, the data will not be kept between tabs.

What is the best practice for the navigation in a web app with authenticated user ?

Comment: i think the best practice for Auth is to create an interceptor and inject the token on all of your protected web requests.

Comment: But how can I deal with the closing of the browser and the logout of the user ?